# Object X pos is drastically changing after screen shake ends

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using the code below to move my player, named balloon, left and right on the x axis by calculating the difference between where you first touched (or clicked) and where you're currently touching, using ScreenToWorldPoint.

```
void Update()
{
    if (gameStarted)
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            firstTouch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            startPos = balloon.position;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            CheckTouchPosition();
    }
}

void CheckTouchPosition()
{
    Vector2 currentTouch = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    float horizontalDif = currentTouch.x - firstTouch.x;
    balloon.position = new Vector2(startPos.x + horizontalDif * 1.2f, balloon.position.y);
}
```

This works normally except after I run into an obstacle and call my trigger shake function, which performs a typical screen shake.  After the screen shake ends the player is translated across the X axis, from what I can tell in the inspector roughly doubling its X position.

```
public class ScreenShake : MonoBehaviour {

Vector3 initialPosition;
float shakeDuration;

public bool shaking;

[SerializeField] float shakeMagnitude = 0.5f;
[SerializeField] float dampingSpeed = 1.0f;

void Update()
{
    if (shakeDuration > 0)
    {
        shaking = true;
        transform.localPosition = initialPosition + Random.insideUnitSphere * shakeMagnitude;
        shakeDuration -= Time.unscaledDeltaTime * dampingSpeed;
    }
    else
    {
        shakeDuration = 0f;
        transform.localPosition = initialPosition;
        shaking = false;
    }
}

public void TriggerShake(float duration, Vector3 position)
{
    shakeDuration = duration;
    initialPosition = position;
}
```

}

I can't figure out why the balloon's X is changing after the screen shake, but it doesn't happen if I don't call that function. I think maybe it has to do with ScreenToWorldPoint being messed up because I'm changing the position of the camera?

EDIT: I forgot to add that the weird repositioning of the balloon ONLY occurs if youre currently holding touching the screen (or holding down the mouse button) when the screen shake occurs.  Otherwise everything happens normally.

Comment: Assuming the second script is attached to the camera it makes sense that `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` gets messed up! A spontanious solution idea might be to use a second camera which is not "shaken" for the `ScreenToWorldPoint` which doesn't render anything.

Comment: This worked great as a workaround! Thanks so much!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped you to figure it out on your own already :)